# UIButton text not visible completely

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard

I have `UButton` that I have set up in Interface builder. The text of the button is *Lets Fix that!* but the font. The width of the button I think is enough to fit in this text. But it appears like this - [image]

The setup is like -

[image]

Comment: Did you check the insets of the title from Edge drop down? Make sure they are all set to zero.

Comment: I would recommend you to redo this step. Delete the layer and add a button again. There should not be any issue with such a simple step, otherwise simply use `[self.myButton sizeToFit];`

Comment: Do you set the title programmatically or just use it as configured in IB? Is there any configuration code involved regarding this button?

Comment: If you programmatically set the title for a button directly through it's label, I've seen this to happen in the past. Make sure you aren't doing that.